# How to configure GHCi to automatically import modules

Tags: haskell, ghci

When I use GHCi, I almost always end up importing `Control.Applicative`, `Data.List`, etc. .  Is there a way to configure GHCi to automatically import those modules.

Also, after importing them, how do I keep the prompt from being insanely long?

```
Prelude Control.Applicative Data.List Database.HDBC Database.HDBC.Sqlite3 System.Directory>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

GHCi looks for its configuration file at

- `~/.ghc/ghci.conf` on Unix-like systems.
- `%APPDATA%\ghc\ghci.conf` on Windows.

The configuration file syntax is simple: it's a list of GHCi commands to execute on startup.

For example, your `ghci.conf` could contain:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char
import Data.List

:set prompt "> "
```

The last line sets the prompt to `"> "` so it won't show all the modules you imported on the command line.

Now you can get to work right away:

```
GHCi, version 6.12.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
> toLower <$> "Hello, world!"
"hello, world!"
>
```

Also, if you decide you don't want `Data.Char` in the middle of a GHCi session, you can remove it with:

```
:m -Data.Char
```

and if you decide you don't want anything but Prelude during a session:

```
:m
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any effect on my Win installation. Seems like ghci.conf is not read. I didn't have this file by default also

Comment: in windows 7 the path is: %APPDATA%\Roaming\ghc

Comment: @fjordrunner: On my system, %APPDATA% expands to `C:\Users\ja\AppData\Roaming`.

Answer (score 23):

GHC will also load any `.ghci` file it finds in the current directory.  It's very useful to do per-project configuration of GHCi.

This is an example from a project I work on:

```
:set -isrc:dist/build/autogen
:set -hide-package mtl
```

The first is there to make sure that the modules generated by Cabal are easy to import.  The second hides `mtl` since this particular project uses `transformers`.

Comment: How do you get this to happen in Windows? I can't name a file ".ghci", and it seems to be ignoring settings in a local "ghci.conf" file.

Comment: I got a `.ghci` file to work on Windows. However, Explorer wouldn't let me rename the file to `.ghci` either. Found 2 ways to get around: **Using Notepad:** In the 'Save as' window  -> Change `Save as type` to `All files (*.*)` or it will add a .txt extension -> Name file `.ghci` and hit save  _**OR**_ **Using Command Prompt:** Browse to the Haskell project's folder with in Explorer -> type `cmd` in the address bar of that window and hit enter. This will open a command prompt starting in that folder -> `mv somefile.ghci .ghci`